# What is the correct form of De Morgan's Law in logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

According to wikipedia ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)), Morgan's Law is:

$$¬ (P \wedge Q) \Rightarrow (¬P) \vee (¬Q)$$

But if you scroll down to 8.2.2 on this page ([link](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~sgc/teaching/pre2012/v231/lecture8.html)), it says that Morgan's Law works as follow:

$$¬ (P \wedge Q) \Rightarrow ¬P \vee Q$$

I believe wikipedia but I have had some excercices where they use Morgan's Law like the other website. Which method is correct?

Comment: Pedantic note: The name "Morgan" is not really the same as the name "De Morgan."

Comment: I suggest you write an e-mail to the author, [Simon Colton](http://ccg.doc.gold.ac.uk/simoncolton/index.html) to notify him of the error.

Comment: @AlexR Ok, will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DeMorgan's Law is really DeMorgan's Laws:

$$\lnot(P \land Q) \equiv \lnot P \lor \lnot Q\tag{1}$$

$$\lnot (P \lor Q) \equiv \lnot P \land \lnot Q\tag{2}$$

Note that in both $(1)$ and $(2)$, the left-hand side and right-hand side  are logically *equivalent*, meaning each side of the equivalence implies the other.

So, the "other website" is most certainly incorrect. It's always good to confirm or challenge what you read on the internet!

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. So the other website is legitimately wrong?

Comment: If they declare what you posted, absolutely wrong!

Comment: @Michiel You should make a truth table to verify what is wrong with your source. If $Q = \text{false}$ and $P = \text{true}$, the RHS evaluates to $\text{false}$ but the LHS evaluates to $\text{true}$.

Comment: This can't be write.  We're on the internet after all.  /s

Answer (score 2):

Good catch, it is definitely *not* true that $$\neg(P \wedge Q) \equiv \neg P \vee Q$$ The website you linked seems pretty unprofessional and I'm guessing whoever wrote it made a (critical) typo. Hopefully nobody else out there saw that and believes it is the correct statement of De Morgan's Law.

Answer (score 0):

A visual representation:
[image: picture]
Basically, collecting the or flips the or into an and.
In the second row, collecting the or transforms Q into not Q.
If the wrong version reported in the website reminds you of some exercises, maybe something similar to the second row was happening! In both rows, what's true is the wikipedia version (expressed in the first row)